# Cannot call a method in the class

Tags: reactjs, redux

Getting started with React and Redux and I have a method in my class to create new lines in a piece of text:

```
class JobPage extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchJob(this.props.match.params.slug))
  }

  getMultiLineText(text) {
    text.split('\n').map((item, key) => {
      return <span key={key}>{item}<br/></span>
    })
  }

  render() {

    const { job } = this.props;

    return(
      {this.getMultiLineText(job.desc)}
    )
  }


}
```

Within my `render()` method I try and call it using the following but the param is not passed. It's `null`:

```
{this.getMultiLineText(job.desc)}
```

If I just do...

```
{job.desc}
```

it prints the description.

Comment: Does it shows any error ? I guess no. Whats the content of `job.desc` and from where are you getting it

Comment: Are there any new line characters?

Comment: Maybe you get null only during initial render? Write the value to console instead!

Comment: The only error is that I can't `split` a null value

Comment: How did you bind the method?

Comment: Please post the entire class, this will clear up a lot of confusion

Comment: I've updated the question to show the whole class

Comment: Whats the content of job.desc and from where are you getting it ?

Comment: I'm getting `job.desc` from a database using Redux

Comment: Sorry, forgot to show how I assign `job` with a value. Updated now.

Comment: hmm cannot reproduce. working fine here  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qmyXxO?editors=0010#0

Comment: I say it again. The job is null during the initial render. You have to handle that case.

Comment: @Sulthan - can you show me a solution then?

Comment: add an if statement, something like `{if (job && job.desc){ return (
      {this.getMultiLineText(job.desc)}
    ) } else {return (<div></div>)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value is probably null during the initial render.

You can solve it for example as

```
{this.getMultiLineText(job.desc || '')}
```

You can also fix it in your reducer.

Comment: So what's happening here? Initial render sends the empty string but once the data arrives from the async request there is a re-render right?

Comment: @tommyd456 Exactly. Actually you should be dispatching actions in `componentDidMount`, not `willMount`. The initial value is the initial value in you reducer which I would assume to be `{}`. You could use `{desc: ''}` instead.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea why the `getMultiLineText` method isn't working by the way? No error, just outputting nothing on screen. There are definitely newlines characters in the text and tried with other delimiters anyway.

Comment: Additionally, if I do `console.log(item)` within the method then it shows the paragraphs that I need so bit confused as to why it's not outputting anything

Comment: @tommyd456, you are not returning anything so no output. Check my codepen link in comments

Comment: That's great. Cheers for the extra help!